# How to Use a Google Script to Change Contents of a Cell When the Sheet Name is Changed by the User

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to allow users to change the name of a sheet; however, when they do I want the new sheet name to appear in a cell.  I basically want the logic to be:

```
If a specific sheet's sheetname is edited {
  cell on another sheet = new sheet name
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to use `onEdit(e)` to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [installable change trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#application_triggers) which runs when a user modifies the structure of a spreadsheet.

### Sample Code:

```
function onOpen(e){
  var ss = e.source;

  //Save the sheet id and sheet name in script properties
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  //Initially delete existing script properties
  scriptProperties.deleteAllProperties();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    Logger.log("id: "+sheet.getSheetId().toString()+", name: "+sheet.getName());
    scriptProperties.setProperty(sheet.getSheetId().toString(),sheet.getName());
  });
}

function onChange(e) {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(e.changeType);
  if(e.changeType=="OTHER"){
    var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    var origName = scriptProperties.getProperty(sheet.getSheetId().toString());
    Logger.log(origName);
    Logger.log(sheet.getName());
    if(origName != sheet.getName()){
      //update script properties
      scriptProperties.setProperty(sheet.getSheetId().toString(),sheet.getName());
      //write new name in the cell
      sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(sheet.getName());

      Logger.log(scriptProperties.getProperties());
    }
  }
  
}
```

### What it does?

1. When the sheet was opened. Create a key-value pair based on sheet's id and the sheet's name. Save it in the script properties using [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)
2. Create an installable onChange trigger.
3. Get the active sheet's id and name, get the original name based on the sheet's id in the script properties using [PropertiesService.getProperty(key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#getpropertykey)
4. Compare original sheet name and the current sheet name. If they are not the same, update the sheet name in the script properties using [PropertiesService.setProperty(key,value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setpropertykey,-value). Then select your range and set the cell value using [Range.setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

### Output:

[image]

```
Apr 10, 2021, 4:28:46 AM    Info    OTHER
Apr 10, 2021, 4:28:46 AM    Info    Sheet1
Apr 10, 2021, 4:28:46 AM    Info    test
Apr 10, 2021, 4:28:46 AM    Info    {1029143107=Checkbox, 1793152938=test}
```

### Note:

- You can remove the deletion of existing script properties in onOpen() if you want.
- You can change the range/cell where you want to write the new modified sheet name.